# Bootstrap: Increase navbar-collapse height when media width < 768px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to increase .navbar-collapse min-height when media < 768px. (dfu is 360px)

```
@media (max-width: 768) {
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse { min-height: 400px !important}
}
```

But this isn't working! Why?

Comment: you need 'px' after your max-width declaration, max-width: 768px

Comment: ops.. bad copy.. it is already 768px.

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? Are you trying to keep the menu open? Or just have a taller header?

Comment: I'll also say that your code as written (assuming the correction of `(max-width: 768px)` works just fine. It does set the height of the menu to a minimum of 400px--when it is opened. See [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/5ZvgUgWiYR)

Comment: Damn! There is an error on the navbar generator! (http://twitterbootstrap3navbars.w3masters.nl/). "px" is missing!